# Does torch_geometric's LinkNeighborLoader/NeighborLoader rename the graph nodes?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-geometric

I am using torch_geometric's LinkNeighborLoader for performing minibatch sampling on my graph. This is my code:

```
train_loader = LinkNeighborLoader(graph, num_neighbors=[10, 10], batch_size=128,
                                  edge_label_index=graph.edge_index)
for batch in train_loader:
   print(batch)
```

I am debugging my code for having a clue of what it does. So I visualize the content of `batch`. Here is what I can see from the debugger console:
[image]
What looks weird to me is the content of `edge_index`. If I am correct, the first element, the tensor `[11, 0]` means that there is an edge from node `11` to node `0` in the minibatch. However, I went to check the original edge list of my whole graph, and such edge does not exist. Does it mean that the library renames the edges as it creates minibatches, in such a way that each subgraph has nodes IDs that start from 0? Or am I missing something? I checked the documentation and nothing is said about this

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself through stepping into the code, and the answer is yes. As we loop through the LinkNeighborLoader, at a certain point the class [SamplerOutput](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/sampler.html#torch_geometric.sampler.SamplerOutput) is called, and the documentation states that it needs nodes in the minibatch to be indexed starting from zero. However, the edge IDs are the same as those in the original graph, and that is how it is possible to tell the original node IDs to which those in the minibatch correspond